# Enlarging images when mouseover using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to enlarge the images when mouseover and reduce the size back to normal after mouseout. I have the following:

```
$('#image img').live("mouseover", function(){
          var $this=$(this);

          $this.attr('width','25%');
          $this.attr('height','25%');


       })
```

The enlarging part works fine but I am not sure how to reduce the size after mouseout. Also, I think my codes are bit ugly and not sure how to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FPKAP/11/ **or** using hover: http://jsfiddle.net/FPKAP/12/

When you will hover over the HULK it will zoomin and on mouse out zoom out.

This should help the need, lemme know if I misunderstood anything please, `:)`

**code**

```
$('#zoomimg').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    $(this).animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'slow');
});

$('#zoomimg').mouseleave(function() {   
    $(this).animate({width: "28%"}, 'slow');
});
```

**code**

```
$('#zoomimg').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(this).animate({
        width: "50%",
        height: "50%"
    }, 'slow');

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "28%"
    }, 'slow');

});​
```

Comment: Why don't you use `.hover()`?

Comment: @Blender I reckon brain freezed within meself `:)` as I read `mouseover` and used `mouseenter` & `leave` yep will make the change now, Thank-you bruvnic!

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the width and height of the image , changes the position of the image (ie) it is enlarged but not in the same position where the original image was present.

Using Scaling property will address this issue.

```
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); 
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/RC7kb/178/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/RC7kb/)

```
$('#image').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
},function(){
    $(this).css({width:"50%",height:"50%"});   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try CSS for this:

```
#image img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#image img:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```