# How to zoom an image with smooth transition in image gallery?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create an image gallery with zoom effect similar to [this one](http://lookbook.nu/user/34805-Frida-J). when the mouse is hovered over an image, it will display the larger version of the image with some additional markups.

**The markup:**

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="image.png" width="150" alt="" />
        <div class="gallery-item-full">
            <img src="image.png" width="250" alt="" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.gallery {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 600px;
}

.gallery-item {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 25px;
    width: 150px;
}

.gallery-item-full {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    top: -50px;
    left: -50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-item-full {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This works, but I want a smooth transition like in the [previous gallery](http://lookbook.nu/user/34805-Frida-J). I'm open to use Javascript/jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FPKAP/12/ (bit different but I made for someone recently)

Hope it fits your need `:)`

link: [Enlarging images when mouseover using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769212/enlarging-images-when-mouseover-using-jquery/11769235#11769235)

**code**

```
$('#zoomimg').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    $(this).animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'slow');
});

$('#zoomimg').mouseleave(function() {   
    $(this).animate({width: "28%"}, 'slow');
});
```

**code**

```
$('#zoomimg').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer").animate({
        width: "50%",
        height: "50%"
    }, 'slow');

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "28%"
    }, 'slow');

});​
```