# Enlarging dynamics images on mouseover using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, image

I have set of image tags with ids such as Image1, Image2, Image3 ....

The 1,2,3 are array index and the tags are created dynamically.   Sometime I may have one image, other times I may have more.  they inline, sized small(100 X 100).

On hover or enter, I need to enlarge the image being hovered over

[example post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769212/enlarging-images-when-mouseover-using-jquery)

This post seem to provide a good solution but the $('#zoomimg') is defined upfront.   Is there a way to self identify the tag id on enter/leave?

The image tags are created as follow:

```js
var i = 0;
images.forEach(function(anImage) {
    var imagePath = url + anImage;
    $('#partImages').append("<img id='" + "partImages" + i++ + "' src=" + imagePath + " height='100' width='100' />");
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `but the $('#zoomimg') is defined upfront. Is there a way to self identify the tag id on enter/leave?` - What do you mean by that?

Comment: I need to figure out if the user is hovering over Image1, image2, image3 ... and so on.  if I know before hand, I just put the id in the selector ... but I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the right selector, like a common class or the generic 'img':

```
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    $(this).animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'slow');
});
```

then u can use `this` to identify the current hovered image

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwty5qL/